# Redirect stdin and stdout in terminal to test program

Tags: c, terminal, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

I have a program that reads from stdin and outputs to stdout. I would like to be able to test this via the terminal.

I know that

```
./program < input_file       # Redirects stdin

./program > output_file      # Redirects stdout

output_file < ./program < input_file # Is this supposed to redirect stdin and stdout at the same time?
```

What if I have sample output in `test.out` that I want to compare `output_file` with? How can I do this in one go?

I have tried various ways of doing this, but no luck so far.

Comment: `././program < input_file > output_file ` should work

Answer (score 1):

You have the redirection to the output file wrong. You need to use `>`, not `<`, and it has to go before the filename. Just like in your second example -- it's no different when you're redirecting both input and output.

```
./program < input_file > output_file
```

What you wrote says to run the program named `output_file`, and redirect its input first from `./program` and then from `input_file`.